# Excel - How to Match duplicate rows, with a unique ID - from a cloned and consolidated version of the same sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I've been given ownership of a document to manage and it's a mess, I want to tidy it up, but have ventured out of my depth unfortunately :(

I have two sheets

- Sheet A (many instances of rows with identical rows of data, each has
  an ID row (that ID has duplicates too))
- Sheet B (a clone of Sheet A, with duplicate rows removed)

Going forward - **Sheet A** has to be removed, but while it does I have to reference what rows have been consolidated and into what rows on **Sheet B**

I want **Sheet A** to have a reference to a unique field on **Sheet B**, where the rows of data and the ref number are identical, this might be done with conditional formatting or formulae but I don't know how. (please see picture of desired effect)

[image: What I would really like to happen]

I need to be able to compare all the data in the row, but... Is it possible to pull in the reference from the consolidated sheet? from **Sheet B** to **Sheet A?**

"The three matches for Value B align to the reference "2" on the sheet, so therefore, the reference / value from that cell will be pulled / displayed / shown on the unconsolidated sheet"

Is this possible?

thanking anyone that even reads this in advance.

Comment: You mean to say apply Conditional Format on Sheet B match with Unique IDs in Sheet A ??

Answer (score -1):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Select required data range in `Sheet B`.
- Reach to **C**onditional Formatting , **N**ew Rules & apply this Formula.

  ```
  =NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(S57, SheetA!P:P,FALSE)))
  ```
- Apply an appropriate Cell Format and finish with **O**k.

**N.B.**

- *You need to flip the formula (sheet name & Cell references) if want to apply Conditional formatting on `Sheet A`.*

**Edited:**

*Following method shows that how records contains unique IDs can be populated when few colums have has duplicated values in both Sheets.*

[image]

- An array Formula in Cell `T78`:

  `{=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(O78&Q78&R78,SheetA!J:J&SheetA!L:L&SheetA!M:M,0)),"","Dupl")}`
- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Finally apply **A**uto Filter to get desire records.

[image]

- *Adjust Cell & Sheet references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi @Rajesh S, I think that the purpose of a solution is to compare all values in row to decide about some Group Number. Not only compare the Ref Number.

Comment: @Muji,, check the Screen shot above,, Sheet A Consolidation Ref No are duplicate compared with Sheet B Ref no are Unique,,, and entire rows have been highlighted,, !

Comment: @RajeshS Hi Rajesh, thank you very much for responding, I was less interested in highlighting the rows, I really want the unique ID to populate from the other sheet if the data in cells Ref Number + Amount 1-5 match the data in the corresponding sheet.

But again thank you for responding, Sir, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, @JackConstantine check the post now I've edited  shows the method, to populate records contains unique ID,,  but has duplicate data in cells Ref Number + Amount ,, I'm sure this work for you ☺