# Excel - Can a field value be displayed from another sheet based on (for example) Conditional Formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets and I want to compare the row data - and (if possible) insert/display a reference from one sheet to another

- **Sheet A** (many instances of rows with identical rows of data, each has
  an ID row (that ID has duplicates too))
- **Sheet B** (a clone of Sheet A, with duplicate rows removed)

[An example of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5vUi.jpg)

I am less interested in highlighting the rows, I really want the unique ID to populate from the other sheet if the data in cells Ref Number + Amount 1-5 match the data in the corresponding sheet.

I suspect it's conditional formatting but I do not know how to achieve this, appreciate your help and time, thank you.

Comment: This question is the same as https://superuser.com/questions/1487836/excel-how-to-match-duplicate-rows-with-a-unique-id-from-a-cloned-and-consol, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Muji, it's slightly different, as I have low reputation I couldn't edit, respond or ask questions through comments about my previous post - so I tried to rephrase it - as I wanted to emphasise that I need to bring in the values from the previous sheet and not just highlight, I apologise if it is not the right thing to.

Although asking this question has meant I am seemingly able to leave comments now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "Ref Number" in Sheet A is cell A1. just put `=INDEX('Sheet B'!B:B,MATCH(A1,'Sheet B'!A:A,0))` in B2 cell, then drag downwards.

hope it helps.

ref : online keyword index match excel